# Harbor Vulnerability Scanner is frozen

Tags: redis, harbor, trivy

I installed Harbor along with the Trivy scanner. During the scan, Redis gave an out of memory error. Foolishly, I performed FLUSHALL in it and now the page with the scan schedule is stuck. The scanner itself works and scans individual images, but now I can't scan all the images in one go. Also, the schedule setting does not work now. I cannot change it to any other value.

Tell me, please, what could be the problem and how can I get everything back, avoiding the loss of images?

[image: interrogation services]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. It took the following:
Connect to DB container
Execute the following commands in psql:

```
delete from scan_report
delete from admin_job
delete from schedule
```